# Join strings in tagging function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, string-interpolation

ES6 introduces string interpolation. But this strings are not only interpolation - they also [can be used with tag function to process values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals).

I don't know what was the purpose of such fucntionality, but I see it useful to somehow process all inlined values. For example, for escaping or encoding. Of course, I can write such code:

```js
function toUrl(s, ...vals) {
  vals = vals.map(encodeURIComponent);

  /// ???
  var res = '';

  for (var q=0; q<vals.length; ++q) {
    res += s[q] + vals[q];
  }

  return res + s[s.length-1];
}

var data='a+b', args='%'
console.log(toUrl `data=${data}&args=${args}`)
console.log(toUrl `data=${data}&args=${args}&t=1`)
```

But I'm surprised I have to write the piece of code after `???`. All natural for me uses of this feature require similar code - merge processed arguments with strings. But I couldn't find corresponding standard method. Does it exist? If not, what was the original purpose of tagging stings and what is typical usage of it?

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568175/178988)

Comment: I guess it just means it's more flexible. One could write a tag function that constructs some sort of object, or whose purpose isn't just to parse the args before merging them in.

Comment: @qxz, yes, it is more flexible. But I'm not asking why tagging is not just processing, I'm asking about some function like `return String.mergeInterpolated(s, ...vals.map(doSmth))`. It seems a common case for me, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, there isn't a standard function to do that.

Comment: @qxz, but that woul mean that some other usage was expected as typical, isn't it? If so, I'm interested what kind of usage it was.

Comment: AFAIK, this type of behavior is what it was "intended for." However, some special function/language construct to make this more elegant wasn't introduced in order to keep it flexible. I've never actually seen custom tags used.

Comment: See the section "The Significance of Tagged Template Literals" at the end of [this post](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/09/30/features-of-es6-part-8-tagged-templates.aspx).

Comment: A new standard helper function like your proposed `mergeInterpolated()` would obviously have its uses, but given there isn't a built-in one (that I know of) there's no reason you can't create it yourself for reuse by whichever of your tag functions need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `String.raw` function:

```
function toUrl(s, ...vals) {
  vals = vals.map(encodeURIComponent);
  return String.raw({ raw: s }, ...vals);
}
```